# why can't start apache if add PHPIniDir Setting to httpd.conf?

Tags: php, apache, server

My Server : Win server 2012 64bit, Apache 2.4 64bit, PHP Version 5.6.13 (x64)

After install Apache 2.4, i can start normal.
But If i add `PHP` to `httpd.conf`

```
PHPIniDir "C:\php"
LoadModule php5_module "C:\php\php5apache2_4.dll"
```

I can't start apache, it show message:

```
Windows could not start the Apache2.4 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1.
```

why can't start apache if add PHPIniDir Setting to httpd.conf?
I test on Win 7, it is ok.

Comment: it works on windows 7. where is it not working?

Comment: Win server 2012 64bit

Comment: are the paths identical on both machines?

Comment: Yes, it the same.

Comment: "review the System Event Log",where is log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause : my php using php_com_net.dll
So i have to install: MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)